# After World War 2, was there a trend to say "defense" instead of "war"?

Tags: warfare, terminology, post-war

In answering [a question whether "defense forces" has any legal meaning](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/63213/4615), I noticed a trend. Before World War 2 military departments and ministries used terms like "war". After World War 2 they switched to "defense".

- US (1949) Department Of War -> Department of Defense
- Germany (1956) Kriegsmarine (War Navy) -> Deutsche Marine (German Navy)
- UK (1964) War Office -> Ministry of Defence

Often this happened when multiple military departments/ministries, such as the army ("war") and navy, were merged into a single entity.

We also got euphemisms such as ["forward defense"](https://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Parliamentary_Departments/Parliamentary_Library/pubs/rp/rp1516/DefendAust) and ["pre-emptive self-defense"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_for_Use_of_Military_Force_Against_Iraq_Resolution_of_2002#International_law:_right_of_pre-emptive_self_defense) for actions which previously would have been called wars.

Is there such a trend? And if so, why?

Comment: Indeed the description is like that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_defence ie 'there is'. I have a very convincing theory, but no refs to back up the explanation…

Comment: Ministry of peace... Orwell 1984.  Set in 1949.

Comment: Hypocrisy is the vaseline of political intercourse.

Comment: Interestingly, the USSR went against the trend during the last years of Stalin: there was the People Commissariat of Defence since 1934, renamed in 1946 to PC of Armed Forces, then changed several military-sounding names until finally becoming the Ministry of Defence in 1953.

Comment: It has lot to do with so called "crimes against peace" at Nuremberg trials. Suddenly, it became the crime to start a war, although Third Reich was not only country in history to do that. Therefore, everybody is suddenly only defending itself or allies or "democracy" etc ...

Comment: @AllInOne: [If you desire peace, prepare for war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si_vis_pacem,_para_bellum).